# why is this algorithm so slow?

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return it's index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

s = "leetcode"
return 0.

s = "loveleetcode",
return 2

This is my solution, simple and easy to understand. However, on LeetCode it reports as "Time exceeds limit", which means it is too slow. This is a O(n^2) solution.

```
public int firstUniqChar(String s) {

        if(s==null || s.isEmpty() ){
            return -1;
        }
        if(s.length()==1){
            return 0;
        }

        char[] ss = s.toCharArray();

        int size = s.length();
        HashSet<Character> repeats = new HashSet<Character>(); 
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

            for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++){
                if(repeats.contains(ss[i])){
                    continue;
                }
                if(ss[i]==ss[j]){
                    repeats.add(ss[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(!repeats.contains(ss[i])){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

However, another version seems to be even slower, not judged as "time exceeds limit", as below:

```
static int firstUniqChar(String s) {

        if(s==null || s.isEmpty() ){
            return -1;
        }
        if(s.length()==1){
            return 0;
        }

        char[] ss = s.toCharArray();

        int size = s.length();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

            boolean unique = true;
            for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++){
                if(ss[i]==ss[j]){
                    unique = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(unique){
                for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                    if(ss[i]==ss[j]){
                      unique = false;
                      break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(unique){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A simple O(n) exists... First pass, count each letter of the string, second pass find the first letter with count 1...

Comment: Then you need a LinkedHashMap to record the counts?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-string-find-its-first-non-repeating-character/

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès And not only is it `O(n)`, even in the worst case ("aaaaa....aaab") you only have to visit `2n` characters.

Comment: @user697911 Any map with `char` key and `int` value (or failing that, their boxed versions) will do. You don't need to care about order while you're counting. But yes, you can do it with an `LHM` and then you don't have to read through the string again. (On the downside you need more memory, but that shouldn't be a problem.)

Comment: @biziclop 2n is O(n), isn't it?

Comment: @user697911 why a LinkedHashMap, a simple array would suffice. Don't try to use complexity when simplicity is available.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do an inner loop.  Trade space for time and keep track of which characters are unique or not as you traverse the string *one time*.

```
public static int firstUniqChar(String s) {

    if(s==null || s.isEmpty() ){
        return -1;
    }
    if(s.length()==1){
        return 0;
    }


    Map<Character, Integer> uniqueCharacterMap = new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    Set<Character> nonuniqueCharacterSet = new HashSet<Character>();

    for ( int i=0; i<s.length();i++) {
        Character c = s.charAt(i);
        if ( nonuniqueCharacterSet.contains(c) ) {
            // character has already been determined to repeat
        } else if ( uniqueCharacterMap.containsKey(c) ) { 
            uniqueCharacterMap.remove(c);  // It's not unique
            nonuniqueCharacterSet.add(c);
        } else {
            // so far, it is unique.
            uniqueCharacterMap.put(c, i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(uniqueCharacterMap.toString());

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> i = uniqueCharacterMap.entrySet().iterator();
    if ( i.hasNext() ) {
        Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e = i.next();
        return e.getValue();
    }

    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("firstUniqChar(leetcode) = " + firstUniqChar("leetcode"));
    System.out.println("firstUniqChar(loveleetcode) = " + firstUniqChar("loveleetcode"));
    System.out.println("firstUniqChar(aaabbbccc) = " + firstUniqChar("aaabbbccc"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple two-pass order(n) pseudo-code algorithm (for strings consisting just the character range 'a' to 'z') might be something like

```
CharFrequency = array [a..z] of integer
for c in InputString do
  inc(CharFrequency[c])
i = 0
while (i < Length(InputString)) and (CharFrequency[InputString[i]] <> 1) do
  inc(i)
if (i < Length(InputString))
  print(i)
else
  print(-1)
```